# Using Pandas, adding a timedelta to a new row in master dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Goal: For a cell in a specific column that has a date within the next 9 months, add a new column to Master with either "Yes", for the date is coming up, or "No", for the date is not coming up.

I'm new to Pandas, so any help would be great. I have one dataframe I'm calling "Master", as the dataframe I am adding everything to to then export to an Excel spreadsheet. With the code below, I created a new dataframe for the date and am trying to say "If the cell is in date, put "Yes" in a new column".

I suspect my issue is that I'm trying to treat Pandas like arrays, but what it's actually doing is creating entirely new indexing when I make a new dataframe and doesn't hold onto how it used to be mapped to master. Is my understanding correct? And if so, how can I accomplish my goal in a more elegant way?

```
def mess_with_time(Master):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    nine_months_in_the_future = str(datetime.datetime.today() + relativedelta(months=+8))
    just_future_month=int(nine_months_in_the_future[5:7])
    just_future_year=int(nine_months_in_the_future[0:4])

    dates = Master[(Master['Contract End Date'] > '{}-{}-1'.format(now.year,now.month)) & (Master['Contract End Date'] <= '{}-{}-20'.format(just_future_year, just_future_month))]
Master['Contract End date coming up?'] = np.where(dates, 'Yes', 'No') #this breaks with 
the error 'Length of values does not match length of index'

def Create_Master(file):
    df = pd.ExcelFile('{}.xlsx'.format(file))

    Master = df.parse('Main').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try rewrite your solution to pandas:

First is possible use [DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) and then create boolean mask by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
now = pd.datetime.now()
months9 = now + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=8)
print (months9)
2018-03-06 15:07:52.850238

rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='3M')
Master = pd.DataFrame({'Contract End Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

dates_mask = Master['Contract End Date'].between(now, months9)
Master['Contract End date coming up?'] = np.where(dates_mask, 'Yes', 'No')
print (Master)
  Contract End Date  a Contract End date coming up?
0        2017-04-30  0                           No
1        2017-07-31  1                          Yes
2        2017-10-31  2                          Yes
3        2018-01-31  3                          Yes
4        2018-04-30  4                           No
5        2018-07-31  5                           No
6        2018-10-31  6                           No
7        2019-01-31  7                           No
8        2019-04-30  8                           No
9        2019-07-31  9                           No
```

---

It seems you need change [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) `Master[boolean_condition]` to `boolean condition` only:

```
dates = Master[(Master['Contract End Date'] > '{}-{}-1'.format(now.year,now.month)) & (Master['Contract End Date'] <= '{}-{}-20'.format(just_future_year, just_future_month))]
```

to:

```
dates_mask = (Master['Contract End Date'] > '{}-{}-1'.format(now.year,now.month)) & (Master['Contract End Date'] <= '{}-{}-20'.format(just_future_year, just_future_month))

Master['Contract End date coming up?'] = np.where(dates_mask, 'Yes', 'No')
```